# Photoshop JSX font size

Tags: font-size, photoshop, jsx

**UPD:** I am using Photoshop CC 5

I am writing a script for replacing strings in Psd text layers. Everything works fine, except that in some of those layers the text size is significantly smaller than that of the original strings. When I log the text size before and after I change the contents, they are indeed different:

```
The old size and new size: 74.601448059082 pt : 38.3819046020508 pt
```

I tried saving the old size in a var and then setting the size after I change the content, but the text size is still wrong (and equal to that second value). What am I doing wrong?

Here is the code I use for replacing the string and logging:

```
var originalString = layerSet.textItem.contents;
var replacementString = "";

replacementString = mmiFromLines(originalString, lines);

var oldSize = layerSet.textItem.size;
var oldKind = layerSet.textItem.kind;

layerSet.textItem.contents = replacementString;

log.writeln("The old size and new size: " + oldSize.value + " " + oldSize.type + " : " + layerSet.textItem.size.value + " " + layerSet.textItem.size.type);

log.writeln("Old kind vs new kind: " + oldKind + " : " + layerSet.textItem.kind);


layerSet.textItem.size = new UnitValue(oldSize.value,  oldSize.type);

log.writeln("The new text size in the layer: " + layerSet.textItem.size.value + " " + layerSet.textItem.size.type);
log.writeln("_____________________________________________");
```

Comment: What version of photoshop are you using?  In CS3 size was just a number - not a unit value. I *think* that changed in CS4.

Comment: Good question, thank you. I forgot to mention that. I am using Photoshop CC 5 (I think 5 is the correct number, but I am not at that computer at the moment). It is certainly a unit value, i was able to log the current value with the number and the kind.